# error: cannot convert value of type '() -> ()' to closure result type 'String' using Swift + PromiseKit

Tags: swift, xcode, promisekit

I am new to promises in Swift and using PromiseKit to try and create a very simple response in a playground and attempt to use it. I have the following code:

```
import UIKit
import PromiseKit

func foo(_ error: Bool) -> Promise<String> {
  return Promise { fulfill, reject in
    if (!error) {
      fulfill("foo")
    } else {
      reject(Error(domain:"", code:1, userInfo:nil))
    }
  }
}

foo(true).then { response -> String in {
  print(response)
  }
}
```

However I get the following error:

```
error: MyPlayground.playground:11:40: error: cannot convert value of type '() -> ()' to closure result type 'String'
foo(true).then { response -> String in {
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is being thrown because the closure you're passing to `then` purports to return a `String`, but no such value is ever returned. Unless you plan on returning a `String` somewhere in that closure, you need to change the closure's return type to `Void`, as follows:

```
foo(true).then { response -> Void in
    print(response)
}
```

Note that closures with the return type `Void` can have their return type omitted. Also, you have an extraneous `{` in the code in your question (I'm assuming this doesn't exist in your actual code, since it compiles).

In addition to that issue, `Error` has no accessible initializers—the initializer you're using in your code actually belongs to `NSError`, and thus your `reject` call needs to look like:

```
reject(NSError(domain:"", code:1, userInfo:nil))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Seems like I have not understood promises well enough. If response -> Void, does that mean fulfill("foo") will still work as expected - in that I will have access to "foo" in the .then as the response?

Comment: Yes. The type after `->` just says what, if anything, _you_ are returning from the closure; `response` remains unchanged.

Comment: I've also tried the ammendments in a playground but it doesn't seem to print  out "foo". On the right hand side instead it says "Promise: UnsealedState"?

Comment: Right, because the `response` is going to be a String, unless an error is thrown (in which case `catch` would be called). `response` does not hold a reference back to `foo`; rather, it contains the response from the original promise (which is of type `Promise<String>`, and thus `response` is a String). But, in your example, passing `true` to `foo` causes an error, meaning that `then` will never be called. Use a `catch` block (which has the error as its parameter) to handle errors.

Comment: I see, but even if I pass `false` to trigger `.then` it still doesn't print "foo" and has the same "Promise: UnsealedState" on the right hand side

Comment: Make sure you have imported `PlaygroundSupport` and that you have included the line `PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true`.

Comment: Worked perfectly, you're awesome!